# iPad needs to be continuously approved to use iCloud account. How to stop that?

Tags: ipad, icloud, notifications

Since a few weeks (never had this problem before that), I am receiving notifications on my Macbook asking to approve my iPad to use iCloud. I have approved it hundreds of times but the notifications keep appearing even if my iPad (called Alabaster) is perfectly able to access my iCloud account.

In the last few days, the problem got more annoying having the notification popping up every hour or so (attached picture). I have checked on the apple forum but I couldn't find any solution.

Can someone help me getting rid of this annoyance?

[image: notification spamming screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried restarting both these devices?

Comment: Yes, I have tried... Nothing changed